# Powershell Regex Match Beginning and End String Doesn't Match?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am attempting to match the following string, it always
begins with `Removing:`
and ends with `--- For User:`

I tried using the following regex:

```
\bRemoving: \w+\ --- For User: \b
```

`Removing: Random_Group_Here --- For User: -` Should Match This

I'm trying to assign this regex to a powershell variable that I can use for a -replace string.

```
$regex = "\[\bRemoving: \w+\ --- For User: \b\]"
```

Comment: If you get rid of the `\b` on either end it works.

Comment: Oh wow you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last [`\b` word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) only matches if there is a word char (i.e. mostly a letter, digit, `_`) after the space at the end of the pattern. Since there is no such a char, the last word boundary prevents from matching.

Either remove the last `\b`, or - if you want to only match that space when not followed with a word char - with `(?!\w)` negative lookahead that will check just that.

You may also replace literal spaces with `\s*` (0+ whitespaces) / `\s+` (1+ whitespaces)  patterns to match any kind and any amount of whitespace between specific chars.

Here is a variation:

```
\bRemoving:\s*\w+\s*---\s*For\s+User:\s*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbRemoving%3A%5Cs*%5Cw%2B%5Cs*---%5Cs*For%5Cs%2BUser%3A%5Cs*&i=Removing%3A%20Random_Group_Here%20---%20For%20User%3A%20-).

Comment: IMO [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/vM3BS1/1) has better explanations.

Comment: @LotPings Regex101 does not support .NET regex. To have a similar .NET experience, I'd recommend Ultrapico Expresso. See a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/0rLnn). I posted a link to an online regex tester (RegexStorm.net) that supports .NET regex syntax, it is a *proof* that the regex will work in Powershell that uses .NET regex, too.